# Can You Pass Nonlinear Functions of Conditioned Variable Through Conditional Expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

In general, nonlinear functions cannot pass through the expectation operator. For example, it is not generally true that $E\left(e^X\right)=e^{E(X)}$ (we can only use Jensen's Inequality here).

However, when one conditions on $X$, is this true? Does it become true, for example, that $E\left(e^X\cdot Y|X\right)=e^XE(Y|X)$?

Thanks!

**Edit**: More generally, is it true that $E(X\cdot f(Y)|Y)=f(Y) E(X|Y)$ for a nonlinear function $f$?

Comment: $E(e^x \cdot y | x)$ has two meanings: a function on $x$, or you assumed that $E(e^x \cdot y | x = 1)$.

Comment: I think it's shorthand for $E(Ye^X|X=x)$, but usually just written $E(ye^x|x)$. Correct?

Comment: (Where $x$ is a random variable -- apologies for my mistakes in notation!)

Comment: afaik, conditional expectation is (somewhat confusingly) used to refer to both the thing you commented and $E[Y | Z]$ (which is a random variable $f(Z)$ that takes the value of $E[Y | Z = z]$ when $Z = z$).

Comment: @Irvan E(eX⋅Y|X) has only one meaning.

Comment: @Did the $X$ was $x$ before so a bit confusing.

Comment: Got something from the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> More generally, is it true that $E(X\cdot f(Y)|Y)=f(Y) E(X|Y)$ for a nonlinear function $f$?

Yes, see David Williams, *Probability with martingales*, or any decent presentation of conditional expectation (say, pages 5-6 of [this](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf)).

Comment: Hi Did, thanks for your reply! What property should I be looking at there? I don't see anything about nonlinear functions.

Comment: Item 6 of Proposition 7.5. Linearity (or the lack of linearity) is offtopic here.

Comment: It might be because I haven't learned about $G$-measurability yet, but to my understanding, I don't think item 6 is strong enough. It only states you can "pull out" the conditioned variable $Y$ from the conditional expectation, not necessarily a complicated function of $Y$, for example $e^Y$. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: And yet item 6 is exactly what you need since $f(Y)$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable for $\mathcal G=\sigma(Y)$.

Comment: Interesting downvote--purely for mathematical reasons, to be sure.